# difference between count(*) and count(id) in impala

Tags: impala

I am freshman using impala. When using function `having` with `count(*)`, I get the result:

> HAVING clause 'count(*)' requires return type 'BOOLEAN'. Actual type is 'BIGINT'.

the sql code is here.

```
select listingid, inserttime, count(*) from listauditreason
    group by listingid, inserttime
    having count(*) >= 2
    limit 20
```

But when replacing `count(*)` with `count(id)`, I get the output. The code is here:

```
select listingid, inserttime, count(listingid) from listauditreason
    group by listingid, inserttime
    having count(listingid) >= 2
    limit 20
```

I am curious about the difference between the two and why I can get the right result in the second way.

Comment: Your first query works for me with Impala 2.10. It may have been a bug that was fixed incidentally.

Comment: Same here, First query is working fine without any issue at my side also. I am  using Impala 2.7 with CDH 5.10.

Comment: In which version you are facing this issue ?-@jiaxiang